# How to write to local PC file from Android emulator app

Tags: java, android, logging

I've been searching for hours and came across a lot of non-sense about read-only this and that and folders and directories and viewing the phone fs, etc. etc.

All I want to do is write to a file that is on my PC for an Android project. I've tried to use local paths (Windows) and have been met with read-only fs system problems, even after completely converting the desired folder to read AND write, Android refuses to get it. I set uses-permissions in my manifest with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE, but no luck.

I've tried to write to the phone, via emulator and actual physical phone, but every search I make turns up nothing (searching for the name of the file).

How can I write to a log file, any file that is where my development source code is? I need to digest JSON data from a web service call and I need it to be written to a local file so that I can work with it. The calls are through Android, currently an emulator, and an install on a physical device, yet no log is written because either a read-only problem which is non-sense, or I just can't find the damn file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you are with your Android device in town and then you want your Android app to read a file from your Windows PC which is at home?

Comment: Haha, no that wasn't quite it, but I thank you for making me rethink how I asked my question. I've written the answer to what my question was supposed to be. Thanks again really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess ultimately the question I asked was just too messy. I wanted to know where I could find "local" logs on my Android device, which I can open and read myself in some text editor. I also wanted to know where "local" logs/files are written to my hard disk when testing the app via emulator.

At this point, I haven't found anything relating to a log file or any arbitrary file being able to be written from an Android app to a local dev PC without being pulled from something like `adb`.

I have found the solution to where I can write arbitrary files to an emulator or phone's filesystem (Source: https://www.journaldev.com/9383/android-internal-storage-example-tutorial):

```
FileOutputStream fos = Main.getAppContext().openFileOutput( "myfile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
fos.write( "Hello, world".getBytes() );
fos.close();
```

Some things to note (Android SDK 26+ at least, others are untested):

1. `FileOutputStream` works very well.
2. "Main" refers to whichever entry point class you're using for your app. It most likely (or must?) extends `AppCompatActivity`.
3. `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` seems to be required.
4. AndroidManifest.xml permissions `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` do NOT seem to be required.
5. **Important**: Files will be saved to `/data/data/YOUR.APP.PACKAGE/files/`.

This was also helpful: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage